# Steam usability, from a user's view

Tags: steam

I've obviously seen the advertising with steam now working properly on Ubuntu, but I've also heard from a few people that a lot of games still don't actually work. So I'm looking for a definitive answer from the users on the pros and cons.

What are people's views? This is basically the only thing stopping me changing to Ubuntu..

Thanks for the input boys and girls.

Comment: Just look up the games you need to have, if they are available to Ubuntu, witch if not don't. You van always use a dual boot, so you have both systems installed.

Comment: Definitely want to avoid dual boot as much as possible. But yeah, that's an option.

Comment: It depends on what games you want to play. Some are available on Ubuntu while others may work with Wine. Could you clarify what games you play on Steam?

Comment: I've just come off a WoW addiction and so I'm looking to explore, so really I'd like to have access to a lot. How easy is it to play a steam downloaded on game on Wine?

Comment: windows steam and linux steam are two different animals.  windows steam works fine in wine given the -no-dwrite flag.  linux steam still doesn't have most of the games available in windows steam.

Comment: +1 to the excellently raised comment as of @CallmeV. It should be an answer. I will vote for it.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo - done

Answer (score 1):

#### Using linux Steam

You can use [this](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=Name&sort_order=ASC&category1=998) page to get an idea of the number of games per platform (please note this may not be totally correct: DLC's, demos, etc should be counted as well). At this moment:

April 2014

- PC (Windows): 2880 games
- Mac: 781 games
- Linux: 401 games

Original data (July 2013)

- PC (Windows): 2046 games
- Mac: 452 games
- Linux: 131 games

If you have an idea of the games you want to play you can check if they are available or not. If not you are a lot more restricted on the choices you can make. Also it should take some (a lot?) time to Mac/Linux catch up with Windows. It really only depends on the creators of games.

#### Using win Steam on wine

As you are using the Windows Steam client, every game should be available to install. The real question is how well each game works, or if they work at all. You can check [Wine Application DB](http://appdb.winehq.org/) how well each game works and tricks/tips.

Every game I tried with Wine worked, but with some glitches. I have never installed any from windows Steam, but installation should be as easy on Windows (you may have then to make some change to make it work with Wine).

Also as wine translates Windows API's you can expect a performance hit.

Comment: "wine" stands for "wine is not an emulator". It does not "emulate" windows, it just provides its own API. Or at least, tries to.

Comment: @Lagerbaer You are right. Maybe "translates"?

Answer (score 1):

Windows steam and linux steam are two different animals. Windows steam works fine in wine given the -no-dwrite flag. Linux steam still doesn't have most of the games available in windows steam.

Move from comments to answers per user request.